# Creating a Video Speed Changer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, manifest

I am creating a video speed changer for BINGE which uses

```
document.querySelector("video").playbackRate = SOME_SPEED_UP_TO_16;
```

to change the speed which works fine although I am making this into an extension and I'm not sure how to order the javascript files

MANIFEST FILE

```
{
      "manifest_version": 3,
            
      "name": "Binge Video Speeder",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "description": "Changes the speed of Binge movies and shows",
       
      "content_scripts": [{
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "js": ["code.js"],
            "matches": ["https://binge.com.au/shows/*", "https://binge.com.au/movies/*"]
      }],

      "action": {
            "default_popup": "index.html",
            "default_title": "Binge Video Speeder"
      },

      "permissions": [
            "storage"
      ]

}
```

POPUP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!-- <script src="content.js"></script> -->
      <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" id="speed_input" placeholder="Enter Speed">
      <button id="set_button">Set</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT (I want this to happen in the popup)

```
window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("set_button").addEventListener("click", set_speed);
}

function set_speed() {
      localStorage["speed"] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("speed_input").value);
      alert(localStorage["speed"])
};
```

JAVASCRIPT (I want this to happen when the binge tabs opens)

```
window.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector("video").playbackRate = localStorage["speed"];
};
```